# Django bootstrap 3 not responsive with form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I write a simple form in Django with this fields: DateField, CharField, Textarea and Autocomplete-light (query the database to autocomplete). All fields works good but when I render in html they are not resizing when the browser window become small. I put jumbotron in a container, only the button actually is responsive... Which is the problem of the other fields?

[image]

html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" type="text/css"/>

<body>
    <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotron">
                  <form method='POST' action'' enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="rica">
                              {{ form.as_table }}
                        </table>
                    </div>
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light-blue btn-md btn-block" value="INVIA RICHIESTA">
                  </form>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your form you want to specify the css class you want the form field to take.  It will then format accordingly.  Bootstrap form fields usually use `class="form-control"` so you want a form something like (this is mostly a copy and paste from an actual form I use):

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('id',)
        widgets = {
            'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'image' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'add1' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'add2' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'add3' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'add4' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'position' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'hours' : forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'salary' : forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'website' : forms.URLInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: I add 'class' : 'form-control' and now works with forms.Textarea (the text area now resize with browser but if the user control the width and the height with mouse than the text area doesn't block on grey container edge like the above image. Anyway not works for autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='fly-autocomplete', attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-placeholder':'Par', 'data-minimum-input-length': 3}),

Comment: If you do not want the user changing the size of the textarea use `style="resize:none"`

Comment: I partial soved the problem in this way: "pip install django-bootstrap-form".
In the html I insert on top {% load bootstrap %} and after I use {{ form|bootstrap }}. Now All content are responsive except for the autocompile-light field. In the forms.py I define auto=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='fly-autocomplete', attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-placeholder':'Par', 'data-minimum-input-length': 3}). How can I make it responsive?

Comment: I cannot see why it wouldn't be responsive now

Comment: Can you show me the HTML created from the template - just for the form

Comment: I don't want the template, I want the html generated by the template.  Right click the webpage, select view page source and copy the form info

Answer (score 0):

put `class="form-control"` to your textboxes and  put `style="resize:none`" to your textarea